# Почему к проекту не подключается nuget пакет System.Data.SqlClient v 4.4.2

Tags: sql, .net, .net-standard

В Visual Studio 2017 создаю проект .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library (.NET 4.7)

Запускаю менеджер пакетов и пытаюсь добавить пакет System.Data.SqlClient. Последняя версия на данный момент 4.4.2. Но ничего не происходит.

Однако если же я выбираю версию пакета 4.4.0 то он успешно добавляется.

В чем причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блин. Вопрос снят.
Каким-то образом процессу мешает наличие в настройках студии еще одного репозитария nuget-пакетов от Syncfusion. Отключил этот репозиторий - и все установилось без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Не смог воспроизвести проблемы, установился без проблем. Попробуйте установить через консоль PM (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console) команда Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.4.2

Comment: У меня ни дома, ни на работе не работает. На какой версии студии вы пробовали? У меня 15.5.4.
Из консоли менеджера пакетов поведение точно такое же.